# How to do syntacting parsing and extract head word using NLTK?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am trying to implement syntactic parsing on a bunch of sentences using NLTK toolkit in Python. And extract head words of each sentence. Can anyone help me figure out how to start ?

Comment: For head-finding in English, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297345/head-finding-rules-for-noun-phrases